# Question regarding the tests of MOOC fi 1 part 6 exercise 3 java

Tags: java

I try to solve the exercise mentioned in the title but can't get the tests to pass.
I'd really appreciate some help as im still a beginner.

For your understanding i' ll post the exercise and explain what i've tried.
At least i try to explain ;)

Pls excuse if i this post does not fullfill all the rules or standards as it's my first time posting and english is not my nativ language.

Thank you

The exercise:

---

The exercise template comes with a pre-defined Message class that can be used to create objects representing messages. Each message has a sender and some content.

Implement the MessagingService class. The class must have a parameterless constructor and contain a list of Message objects. After that, add the following two methods to the class:

public void add(Message message) - adds a message passed as a parameter to the messaging service as long as the message content is at most 280 characters long.
public ArrayList getMessages() - returns the messages added to the messaging service.
Tip! You can find out the length of the string using the length() method associated with the string.

---

If i try to submit the exercise i get the following error.

An error occurred during execution of the program. Try out your program using the following code:

```
MessagingService ms = new MessagingService();
System.out.println(ms.getMessages());
Message m = new Message("sender", "message");
ms.add(v);
System.out.println(ms.getMessages());
```

---

If i try the code listed above in my main class i get an error for ms.add(v)
(cannot find symbol for variable v)
if i change ms.add(v) into ms.addMessage(m) it prints Message m.

Below is the code

**MessageServicing class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MessagingService {
    private ArrayList<Message> liste;
 
    
    public MessagingService(){
     this.liste=new ArrayList<>();
     
        
    }
    public void addMessage(Message message){
        int max=280;
        if(message.getContent().length() <=max){
        liste.add(message);   
    }
    }
        public ArrayList<Message> getMessages(){
            return this.liste;
        }
    }
```

---

Messageclass

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Message {

    private String sender;
    private String content;

    public Message(String sender, String content) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.content = content;
    }
    public Message(String content){
        this.content=content;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.sender + ": " + this.content;
    }

    // created using the "insert code" feature of NetBeans
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Message other = (Message) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.sender, other.sender)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.content, other.content)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

Comment: The problem is simply that in the class MessagingService, you named the method "addMessage" instead of "add".

Comment: Some other unrelated tips to write better code: 1) all fields in all classes can be final. 2) code against interfaces,  do not declare as ArrayList (implementation) but as List (interface). 3) Each time you implement equals, do not forget to implement hashCode as well. 4) in the method add, you don't need to declare the field max, you can write directly <=280 in the if block.

Comment: yes, thank you. it's something i didn't change before posting it and was part of me trying things to get it to work.

Comment: it still does not want to take the (v) part so.

Comment: Of course because you named the message "m", not "v". So it's "m" that you should add to ms, not "v"

Comment: that's the problem. the test is part of the exercise. i can't change it.
if i use m the code does compile. but if i use the test that is part of the exercise it does not even compile due to the error.
and thanks alot for your time

Comment: It doesn't make sense then, v is not a declared symbol and as you posted, the code can't compile. You are surely missing something in the exercise, are you sharing all the information you have?

Comment: yes i am sure. 
the exercise part i posted above, is the complete text of the exercise.

Comment: I'm sorry but it really doesn't make sense, they can't expect to add(v) if v is not a declared symbol, that's basic java (the compiler would fail to compile). If you have a link to the exercise, I can have a look. But I'm pretty sure they do `ms.add(m)` and if they don't, then this v must come from somewhere you're not sharing with us

Comment: no need to be sorry, im really happy you are trying to help.

Exerciselink is : https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-6/1-objects-within-objects

Comment: It asks me to login to see the exercise, so I can't see it. If you submit your code naming the method "add" instead of "addMessage" in your class MessagingService, what does it say?

Comment: I submitted it again after running it with (m) and it passed, but it didn't pass the local  tests.
Anyway it is solved now thank you really much for your help, even so i still don't understand why it would order me to run the test with (v).

Comment: I think it's simply a typo in their message. They must be running the code with m (else it wouldn't compile), but probably they forgot to update the description they print for help. Anyway, as a suggestion, I don't know what is this website you're following to study java but by a quick look there are several bad practices implemented in their examples, I don't think you're learning java by the best source

Comment: It is part of the MOOC fi (Multiple open online courses finnland) of the university of hellsinki.
i use it because it is free and i wanted to see if im able to understand and learn  java, as im only doing it in my freetime and i was interested in learning java by a kind of guided course.
what source would you suggest to use if i may ask.

Comment: If you're really a beginner, I suggest you https://www.hackerrank.com/java-tutorial/ . The day you'll be interviewing for a software developer position, you'll most surely solve an exercise on this platform. It has a lot of nice theoretical references plus a lot of nice exercises that make you improving not only your java skills but generally speaking your software development thinking. Happy learning!

Comment: thank you for your patience and your help Matteo i really appreciate it.
as this is my first post may i ask you how i can mark this question as solved and how to honour (thank) you on your profile ? 
i will look into the link you suggested :)

Comment: I should have posted it as an answer, you can't accept a solution in comments. You can answer your own question and mark it as answered (in 2 days I think), no need to honour me I'm glad if I could be of help :)

Comment: I appreciate it even more then.
Have a nice evening and a nice rest of the weekend :)